# System.NullReferenceException when trying to pass an Object

Tags: c#, object, xna, parameter-passing

For practice we have to make Tetris and we were given a template project to work with in Visual Studio (with XNA). Now that we got the gist of it down, I'm trying to introduce sounds. However, `soundengine` is declared is within the `GameWorld` class, but the actual gameplay events trigger in `TetrisGrid`, again a separate class.

Now one solution would be to move the entire initialization of it to the `TetrisGrid` object, but we sometimes want to play sounds in `GameWorld` too, for instance in a menu screen. Also having the music controls there would be a lot more practical, since the `TetrisGrid` may be reset after losing/winning the game.

The `soundengine` spawns from here:

```
namespace tetrisXNA
{
    class SfxHelper
    {
        private SoundEffect[] sfxLibrary;
        public SfxHelper(ContentManager Content)
        {
            this.sfxLibrary = new SoundEffect[2];
            this.sfxLibrary[0] = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("pop");
            this.sfxLibrary[1] = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("latch");
        }

        public void popRow()
        {
            this.sfxLibrary[0].Play();
        }

        public void latchBlock()
        {
            this.sfxLibrary[1].Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Which works just fine when using it in the object you initialised it, but trying to pass it to the `tetrisgrid` object (both using ref and normally). All classes are within the same namespace.

```
public GameWorld(int width, int height, ContentManager Content)
        {
            [...]
            this.soundengine = new SfxHelper(Content);
        }
```

Constructor where the soundengine is assigned (in `gameworld`).

The tetrisGrid object constructor:

```
public TetrisGrid(Texture2D texture, SfxHelper soundEngine)
        {
...
            this.random = new Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            this.soundengine = soundEngine;
...
        }
```

The soundengine is declared above as `public SfxHelper soundengine;`. So how do I make the same instance of it accessible to different objects/layers, how to pass it correctly? I've tried looking into the static modifier but I've yet to implement that correctly, because it does suit the job as only one sound engine is really required.

Comment: Oh looks like I figured it out, I had to declare it in the GameWorld class as "public static SfxHelper soundengine" and can now access it through "GameWorld.soundengine". Is this really the best way to make objects accessible for every other class?

Comment: you can have a public static SfxHelper class and dont keep any thing in the construstor code. But write a seperate method something like 'SetContent' There you have the currently written constructor code. call it where ever you have to change the content. Please let me know any additional info needed

Comment: @kishoreVM It would be nice to have it load its content on initialize to keep the clutter away. My only problem with the static approach is that it only makes it accessible to everybody or to 1 other. How would I make it accessible to specific objects? I can't help but to question this approach because it makes everything global while that really isn't needed either...

Comment: If the same instance you want to use across then public static is the way. you can also refer topic on singleton pattern. but however if you want to restrict acccess of your object to certain classes then you try doing this way create a seperate public static class but having your sfxHelper as private and should have a public method that returns sfxHelper sole instance but you will check whether to return actual or null like the below. the signature of that method takes the calling obj instance.

Comment: public SfxHelper GetSoundEngine(object obj)
{

 if (obj.GetType() == typeof(ParticularClass))
 {
  // then return actual 
 }
 else
 {
         //else return null
 }

} // here based on number of classes you permit to access this you wither use if else if or switch  cases

Comment: @user2058978 Generally you should avoid **static** in games because it makes it difficult to perform _tear down_ such as at the end of a _level_ or game _session_.  Non-statics are easy to `dispose`.  Another important time to tear-down is when the user Alt-Tabs to another app, you should gracefully discard expensive resources if your app does not do much in the background. _[Would you like to know more?](http://www.amazon.com/Game-Engine-Architecture-Jason-Gregory/dp/1568814135/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1412861872&sr=1-3&keywords=game+engine+architecture)_